# Streamming data to Druid Server

Tags: java, streaming, real-time, druid

I have ad log data and I want to send it real-time to Druid server. But, the issue is that between Tranquility and Kafka. Which is the best method to ingest data real-time. Because, when using kafka it make a bundle of error. I try to use Tranquility.
Can anyone who have experiences on this issue help me ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem? I don't think I understand the question. If you're just asking about how to do this in general, the question is probably too broad for stackoverflow. Rather do a google search... you can hardly be the first one to have that problem.

Comment: The purpose of my question is that: between using Kafka and Tranquility for real-time ingestion ad log data, which is the best way ? I prefer to ask the people who has experiences on this issue. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use the new kafka indexing service. This service is independent from tranquility and has better guaranties.
Please read this doc http://druid.io/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/kafka-ingestion.html

Comment: Can you give me the reason for using Kafkar ? Give me some links if possiblle. Thanks

Comment: The one and main reason that Kafka based ingestion is the way to go is to be able to provide guarantees of exactly-once ingestion. The design of Tranquility doesn't provide such guaranties. Hope that helps.